# Is it possible to get a notification when the user stopped viewing a MP4 file?

Tags: nginx, mp4, rtmp

I'm using NGINX MP4 module to stream MP4 files on my server.

To get a notification when a user starts playing a file, I use the auth_request directive.

Is there something similar I can use to detect when the user stops playing the file?

Thank you for your help.

Pedro

Answer (score 0):

Not through the same method. The player or webpage could download the entire video and never play it, or only play part of it, and there server will never know. The type of metrics you are looking for must be part of the player or webpage.